# D3: position tooltip outside Donut Chart

Tags: d3.js

I have made a basic Donut chart using d3 and added a tooltip to this donut.

**Problem:**
When i hover on the left side of the donut, tool tip appears outside.
[image]

But when i hover on left side of donut the tooltip appears inside of donut
[image]

How do i keep the tooltip always outside?

Comment: Hello @Vishu, I know this issue is closed long ago. But from that what I see, I like the builded donut chart very much and this is actually that what I am trying to build. Can you tell, how you have implemented this? I would be very grateful for your help! This is the link to my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73371727/d3-donut-chart-show-progress-of-a-data-point-by-saturating-color  Maybe you could share your experience :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by setting appropriate top and left to the tooltip, onMouseMove with help of **event.pageX** and **event.pageY**

```
.on("mousemove", function(d, i) {
  tooltip.style("top", event.pageY - 10 + "px");
  if (event.pageX < 360) {
    tooltip.style("left", event.pageX - 80 + "px");
    d3.select(".donut_arrow_box").attr("class", "left donut_arrow_box");
  } else {
    tooltip.style("left", event.pageX + 10 + "px");
    d3.select(".donut_arrow_box").attr("class", "right donut_arrow_box");
  }
})
```